# Can't find 'Take Bug Report' option anywhere on Redmi 7A (MIUI 11)

Tags: android, bug-reporting, miui

Recently, the MIUI 11 update had come and after updating it, I can't find 'Take Bug Report' anywhere inside developer options. Is there anything new that I don't know about 'Bug Report' like it was renamed or something? I searched in [docs](https://developer.android.com/) and MIUI forums but couldn't find anything that says anything about it. Although, there is a new option called 'System Trace'. But, 'Bug report' and 'System Trace' are totally different. Let me say what I know about them first. How I used to know about bug reports is that it would take all the reports since last 'Power On' to the 'Bug Report' taking time. And what system trace is doing is that it's recording the current system logs when I click 'Record Trace' or whatever. So, how can I take 'Bug Report' or am I just missing something here? Please tell me if there's any alternative or may I just wait for the next MIUI update to fix it?

Comment: `adb` can be another option. You can grab a bugreport through command line: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report#bugreportadb

Comment: I almost forgot about adb, finally generated Bug Report but facing problem finding the zip file

Comment: sorry to bother for this small issue, found it inside the adb folder, i was actually looking inside the device.

Answer (score 3):

Go to setting -> About phone -> All specs -> click 5 or 4 times on cpu and Generate bug report